# How to open .net WPF application remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, remote-desktop

I am new in this scenario. So I don't know more about this.

I have created "ABC.exe" WPF application in PC1. Now I have installed this WPF application in PC2.

I want to open this application in PC2 from PC1. Which method is useful or which way is good?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: The fact your program is using WPF is irrelevant.

Comment: None of the tags are really relevant, and I struggle to see why you'd even include asp.net.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I am sorry man, but I am new in this chapter, can you suggest me and help me out? Thanks!!

Comment: You can use "process" but remotely don't know about it @NiteshKothari

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the PsExec tool from Sysinternals ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx )

Comment: Dai, thanks brother, I show that link but can you do me one favor? My PC2 IP is "XXX.XXX.X.132". can you post the code with this IP? Thanks @Dai